# emailing a survey from within the survey

Tags: survey, outgoing-email

I have a SharePoint survey and we want to add the option for the survey to be emailed once completed. There is an option to add the address book and  option to select names.  But when the survey is submitted,it does not send.  Does, anyone have any suggestions for how to make this work,or if its even possible?

Answer (score 0):

So what you would need to do is build a workflow that would start once the item is created in the list, meaning when the person submits the survey it would then start the workflow. Hopefully you have access to SharePoint Designer, that would make the process much easier. You could just have it do an e-mail action and you could pre-populate the people that need to receive the e-mail along with the subject, and body text.

If you have access to SharePoint Designer that would be easiest.

1. Open SharePoint Designer
2. Click in the Workflows section under Site Objects
3. Click List Workflow down and select your survey list
4. Give the workflow a name
5. When the designer window comes up, type the word e-mail and it should prompt you for the e-mail action.
6. Fill in the necessary info for the e-mail
7. Publish the workflow
8. Click on workflows and select your newly created workflow
9. Make sure its set to Start on Item create

All set!